# indefinite article with proper names

Tags: grammar, articles

Please help me decide which of the following two sentences in correct:

1. Twenty-year-old Thomas Smith has been running his own business for already 2 years.
2. A twenty-year-old Thomas Smith has been running his own business for already 2 years.

It's the very first sentence that serves as a kind of introduction to the text. I personally consider the second sentence to be correct, because to my mind the indefinite article shows that this Thomas is one of many (by analogy with "there is a Mr. Smith wants to see you") Am I right?

Comment: Word order: "...for two years already" OR "...already been running his business for two years".

Answer (score 0):

> "Twenty-year-old Thomas Smith has..."

Here you have already defined "Thomas Smith".

> "Thomas Smith, who is twenty years old."

Unless you knew several "twenty-year-old Thomas Smiths", it would make no sense to use the indefinite article.

Then again, it would be current usage to say

> "A Thomas Smith (a certain Thomas Smith) has been running that business...."

Answer (score 0):

This is a normal use of an indefinite article to indicate the appearance of a new referent in a narrative. All subsequent articles determining that referent are definite. Note the effect of changing *the* to *a* (and vice versa, ad libitum) in the following:

- ***A*** man stood on the corner.
  **The** man was wearing a sweatshirt.
  Unfortunately, that was all **the** man was wearing.

Thus the first use of *Thomas Smith* is indefinite (even if named, the name does not yet refer to anything); after that, coreferential uses of *Thomas Smith* are definite.

If an article is desired, either definite or indefinite articles may be used, even with proper names.
The article that applies in the introductory use is the indefinite one. But it's not required.